# Update Dev Tools content based on active browser tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Developer Tools on a second monitor in full screen and the browser itself on the primary monitor. Currently I have to "inspect element" every time I change to a new tab.

Is it possible to make Dev Tools refresh and adjust to the active tab when I change to the new tab in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DevTools belongs to its tab, so you need to initiate a new devtools for each tab you want to inspect. There's currently no way to have an undocked devtools instance where you can change its debug target.

Comment: Is there a solution to when I have opened 2 different devtool windows for 2 different tabs and I switch between the tabs so that the corresponding devtool window is made the active one on the second monitor?